# How to delete full object with javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, object

I tried it, but `delete` doesn't work.

```
var x = {"y":42,"z":{"a":1,"b":[1,2,3]}};

alert(x.y);
delete x;

alert(x.y); // still shows '42'
```

How to delete the full object crossbrowser?

Edit:
`x = null` also doesn't work

Comment: Would be a good idea to mention in which browsers it doesn't work...

Comment: what do you mean x = null doesn't work?  If you are referring to accessing it, x.y will most certainly fail after assigning null to x.  If you are referring to reclaiming memory, then the object that was assigned to x will be cleaned up by garbage collection, if there are no other references to it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can only use the delete operator to delete variables declared implicitly, but not those declared with var. You can set x = null or x = undefined

Answer (score 4):

You cannot delete a variable or a function. Only a property of an object. You can simply assign:

```
x = null;
```

if you want to clear its value.

UPDATE: clarification regarding functions:

```
>> function f1() {console.log("aa");}
>> f1();
aa
>> delete f1;
false
>> f1();
aa
```

But if you declare a global function as a window attribute, you can delete it:

```
>> f1 = f1() {console.log("aa");}
>> delete window.f1;
true
```

The same is for variables:

```
>> a = "x";
>> console.log(a);
x
>> delete window.a;
true
>> console.log(a);
ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

But:

```
>> var a = "x";
>> console.log(a);
x
>> delete a;
false
>> console.log(a);
x
```

Comment: Not true, regarding functions.  See my comment to @Spudley below.

Comment: You can delete a function if it's a member of an object. But you cannot remove a globally defined function.

Comment: What do you mean by globally defined? by default, a global variable exists under the 'window' scope chain.  Try it form the Chrome console `func1 = function(){}`, then `delete window.func1`.  It will delete successfully

Comment: I updated my answer to show what I meant under "you cannot delete a function".

Comment: @Matt running this kind of JS code on a developer console is fraught with danger because the code is eval-ed, and that may lead you to incorrect conclusions. See http://perfectionkills.com/understanding-delete/ to understand why.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to delete objects in JavaScript. The object will be garbage collected after all references to it are removed. To remove the reference, use:

```
x = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't delete an object from the global namespace in Javascript.

You can `delete` objects within `x`, but not `x` itself.

Comment: From Chrome console, I can do `window.func1 = function(){}`, and then `delete window.func1`.  I can also do `func2 = function(){}` followed by a delete.  However, I can not do `function func3(){}`. Calling delete on that returns false, and the function remains.

Answer (score 1):

Try `x = null;` or `x = undefined;`.